# Cannot load PSReadline module. Console is running without PS

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-online, powershell, online, pnp-powershell

Getting below error when trying to open SharePoint Online Managment `Shell`.

> Cannot load PSReadline module. Console is running without PSReadline.
>
> Import-Module : Errors occurred while loading the format data file:
>
> C:\Program Files\SharePoint Online Management
>
> Shell\Microsoft.Online.SharePoint.PowerShell\Microsoft.Online.SharePoint.PowerShell.ps1xml,
>   , C:\Program
>
> Files\SharePoint Online Management
>
> Shell\Microsoft.Online.SharePoint.PowerShell\Microsoft.Online.SharePoint.PowerShell.ps1xml:
>   The file was skipped
>
> because of the following validation exception: File C:\Program
>   Files\SharePoint Online Management
>
> Shell\Microsoft.Online.SharePoint.PowerShell\Microsoft.Online.SharePoint.PowerShell.ps1xml
>   cannot be loaded. A
>
> certificate chain processed, but terminated in a root certificate
>   which is not trusted by the trust provider..
>
> At line:1 char:1
>
> - Import-Module Microsoft.Online.SharePoint.PowerShell -DisableNameChec ...
> - ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
> - CategoryInfo : InvalidOperation: (:) [Import-Module], RuntimeException
> - FullyQualifiedErrorId : FormatXmlUpdateException,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.ImportModuleCommand

Please suggest.

Comment: Could you try to open the SPO PS as Administrator and type `Install-Module PSReadLine`

Answer (score 0):

Download 64-bit of SharePoint Online Management shell from [here](https://www.microsoft.com/en-in/download/details.aspx?id=35588)

A reference about installing SharePoint Online Management shell is given [here](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/sharepoint-online-how-to-install-sharepoint-online-management-shell/)